# In Flutter, can I put FutureBuilder<String> inside a Timer?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter, can I put FutureBuilder inside a Timer? Is there a way to automatically refresh the GUI using FutureBuilder? Or any other possible way?

Comment: see my answer using a function that calls itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what is your goal, but if you want to recreate your widget every X seconds with different strings you can use Future.delayed:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class RefreshWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  RefreshWidget({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _RefreshWidgetState createState() => _RefreshWidgetState();
}

class _RefreshWidgetState extends State<RefreshWidget> {
  static List<String> myStrings = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"];

  int i = 0;
  String _current = myStrings[0];

  void rebuild() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      setState(() {
        _current = myStrings[++i % 4];
      });
      rebuild();
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    rebuild();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(child: Center(child: Text(_current)));
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I stop the repetition? like as for your example if _current = 10 , I want to stop the repetition/loop

Comment: You can juste change `rebuild();` to `if (i < 10) rebuild();`

Answer (score 0):

This package might help to refresh your widget periodically.

https://pub.dev/packages/refreshable_widget

```
   Flexible(
      child: RefreshableWidget<num>(
        initialValue: challenge.userParticipation!.donePercent,
        refreshCall: () async {
          final challenge =
               await cadoo.getChallengeDetail(
                   id: widget.challengeId,
               ); 
               return challenge.userParticipation!.donePercent;
        },
        builder: (context, value) {
          return DonePercentWidget(
            percent: value,
          );
        },
       ),
     ),
```